# find the number of ways to choose an ordered pair $(a, b)$ of numbers from the set {${1, 2, 3, ..., 10}$} such that $|a-b|\leqslant5$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, absolute-value

find the number of ways to choose an ordered pair $(a, b)$ of numbers from the set {${1, 2, 3, ..., 10}$} such that $|a-b|\leqslant5$

**My Approach:**

I wrote down all the solutions, choosing $a=10$, $a=9$ and so on. Adding up all those solutions gave me the answer $70$. I think I counted all of the solutions but the answer is $80$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct if the numbers cannot be repeated. You get $80$ if you assume that the same number can be picked twice. For $a \in (1, 5)$, you have $6$ choices each which is $a \leq b \leq a + 5$. That leads to $6 \times 5 \times 2 = 60$ solutions. Multiplication by $2$ is as they are ordered pairs.

Now for $a \in (6, 10)$, the number of choices reduce by $1$ for every next number. So for $6$, we have five choices ($6$ - $10$), for $7$, four choices and so on.

That leads to $2 \times (5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1) = 30$ solutions.

Now note that $a = b$ should be counted only once i.e. we counted $(1, 1), (2, 2)...(10, 10)$ twice when we multiplied by $2$.

So the answer is $60 + 30 - 10 = 80$. This is assuming that the same number can be picked twice.

Comment: so how do I assume that I can select 'repeat'? I specifically didn't make cases for those 10 solutions.

Comment: @ShlokJain it is not your mistake. The question should have been more clear. If you are faced with ambiguous situations like this in an exam, all you can do is to upfront and clearly mention what is the assumption that you have made for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Cause we find: ordered pair (a,b)

Case 1:
Assume a = b then:
we have 10 pair ex: (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), ..., (10,10)

Case 2:
Assume a > b then:
$ 5 \ge a-b > 0 $
$ \Rightarrow b+5 \ge a \gt b $

```
    Notice: For each b (from 1 to 5) we can get: 
              5 value for a ( from b+1 to b+5)
            --> The number of way: 5 * 5 =25
     For each b ( from 6 to 10) we can get: 
              10 - b value for a
            --> the number of way: 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10
```

the number of way for case 2 is:
$ 5 \times 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 35$

Case 3:

Swap (a,b) from case 2:

```
 the number of ways: 35
```

So we counted: 10 + 35 +35 = 80 pair

`